# Use UINotificationFeedbackGenerator in pythonista Objc_util

Tags: python, objective-c, pythonista, haptic-feedback

I'm trying to use UINotifcationFeedbackGenerator in pythonista,

```
from objc_util import *
feedbackGenerator = ObjCClass('UINotifcationFeedbackGenerator')

feedbackGenerator = feedbackGenerator.alloc().init()
feedbackGenerator.notificationOccurred(0)
```

but running this causes the app to crash, with the error file saying

```
called more times than the feedback engine was activated
```

so searching it up, it seems the feedback Generator isn't tread safe, but using on_main_thread() didn't work either (or i'm just using it wrong). Through strangely enough, adding it to a method called by ui works [here](https://github.com/shaun-h/Tutorial-Haptic-Feedback-in-Pythonista/blob/master/stage3.py)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late ;-), but: You are overwriting feedbackGenerator which will cause the crash:

```
feedbackGenerator = feedbackGenerator.alloc().init()
```

Try this:

```
f = feedbackGenerator.alloc().init()
f.notificationOccurred(0)
```